# $http.get not sending data in the body of the request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Using angular v1.3.1 i got a singular the following problem trying to implement a facade for making http request to a REST + JSON interface in the backend of the web app.

I got something like this in the code:

```
findSomething(value: number): ng.IPromise<api.DrugIndication[]> {
  const getParams = { 'param' : 'value' };
  const config:ng.IRequestShortcutConfig = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    data: getParams
  }
  return this.$http.get(url,config);
}
```

And when the times comes to invoke it, i got an 400 Bad Request (btw: Great name for a band!) because the backend (made with Play for Scala) rejects the request inmediately. So making an inspection in the request i see that no data is being send in the body of the request/message.

So how i can send some data in the body of and HTTP Get request using angular "$http.get"?

Additional info: This **doesn't** happen if i the make request using the curl command from an ubuntu shell. So probably is an problem between Chrome and angular.js

Comment: sounds like a CORS issue, most likely

Comment: why don't you use POST?

Comment: @PankajParkar because usually a find request typically is performed with GET method.. but i could change for a POST, and that would work. Even so, i would like to know is someone knows a workaround for this that doesn't involve changing the URL request method.

Comment: A GET request cannot have a body in HTTP. This is not specific to Chrome or Angular, it's by definition in the HTTP specifications. If you want to send a body in your request, it needs to be a POST, PUT or PATCH. Curl will automatically switch to POST as soon as you specify any data to send, as can be seen if you add -v in your invocation.

Comment: Why on Earth, would you need a body for a GET request..?

Comment: lads, as far I know there is no rule that explicitly forbids to send a body in a GET request, in a matter of fact I made it via curl.

Comment: probably related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/2495283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the network tab in chrome development tools you will see that this is a pre-flight OPTIONS request (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)).

You have two ways to solve this.

1. Client side (this requires that your server does not require the application/json value)

   - GET, POST, HEAD methods only
   - Only browser set headers plus [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
   - Content-Type only with:

     - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     - multipart/form-data
     - text/plain
2. Server side

   - Set something like this as a middleware on your server framework:

     ```
     if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
         w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
         w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
         w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization")
         w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400") // firefox: max 24h, chrome 10min
         return
     }
     ```

For your specific framework [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter) should work

Comment: Thanks for the info, could be useful, but the problem isn't CORS. I suspect that angular js or Chrome are enforcing the fact stated at the "The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI." (extracted from https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). I guess, there is no point in trying to force my "naive" approach.. i will use get with URL params.

Answer (score 1):

Using config.data will send the data in the request body, use

```
config.params = getParams
```

This is from the documentation :

params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters